# How to find the force that has to be pulled to a set of two blocks given the condition that a wire can break?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> The figure from below shows a set of three pulleys joined by a cable
>   with one end tied to the roof along one of the pulleys. From the
>   center of the first pulley from the right a block of mass "$m$" is
>   hanging as indicated. Meanwhile the other pulley from the right is
>   supported by a stand where a Force $F$ is pulling to the right. It is
>   known that the mass of the block is $2\,kg$ and it takes $3\,s$ to
>   impact to the ground starting from rest. Given these conditions: Find
>   the value of the force $\vec{F}$. (Assume: $g=10\,\frac{m}{s^2}$).

The alternatives given are as follows:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&4\,N\\
2.&6\,N\\
3.&8\,N\\
4.&10\,N\\
5.&12\,N\\
\end{array}$

What i've attempted to do here was to establish this equation.

$F-mg=ma$

But the problem lies on exactly how to define the acceleration in this system. If I go on this route:

$v_f^2=v_o^2+2a\Delta y$

Then

$v_f^2=0+2a\Delta y$

It can be seen from the graph that $\Delta y = 9\,m$

Therefore this can be plug into the previous equation:

$v_f^2=0+2a (9)$

But it also mentions that the time elapsed to hit the ground is $3\,s$. Therefore:

$v_f=v_o+at$

$v_f=0+3a$

If I were to use this into the preceding equation I end up with:

$(3a)^2=0+2a(9)$

And this does produce a contradiction. What am I doing wrong?. Can someone help me here?.

Comment: Where is the contradiction?. You simply can find $a$ from the final equation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any contradiction. From the final equation $9a^2=18a$ we can find the solution $a=2$ (for $a\ne0$), that can be used to find $F$.

(But note that the correct equation is $mg-2F=ma$ because the cable is tied to the roof)

Comment: I would write $2F - mg = ma.$ This accounts for the parts of the cable on both sides of the pulley.

Comment: Maybe $mg-2F=ma$ ?

Comment: It depends what sign each variable has. I assumed $F>0,$ $g>0,$ and $a < 0$ since the object is accelerated downward. (So if it were falling freely I would give it acceleration $-g$.) Whichever way you do it, there is a gravity pulling downward, two pieces of cable pulling up, and $ma$ is the result.

Comment: @EmilioNovati During the rush of my calculations I overlooked that fact. Thanks for pointing out that what I ended was a quadratic expression and from it can be obtained two solutions. Hence in this question $a=2$, from it  can be established the Force.

Comment: @DavidK Thanks for adding that comment. I was also about doing that comment for the negative downward acceleration. But I'm a bit confused of the meaning of the negative in front of the acceleration. Does it mean the direction?. Or does it mean the object is decreasing its velocity?. Sorry if this sounds dumb but I often get confused with that matter.

Comment: @ChrisSteinbeckBell negative acceleration means velocity is changing toward the negative. So positive velocity decreases toward zero, zero velocity becomes negative, negative velocity becomes more negative.